# Blank screen after installing nvdia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.04, gpu-driver

I have ubuntu 19.04 on an ASUS zenbook 13. I was running the system with "nomodeset" in the grub settings.

I tried to install a new nvidia 418 driver, by using the suggested path (set a MOK password for safe booting system). After doing that, the system is stuck at this point from 30 mins

I could not solve it, how to do?!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG1zH.jpg)

Comment: Does it work if you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: No, Actually I tried to change the driver from the software updater and now my system us fully stacked try to loading. It is stuck on "Starting update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"